# MERN: How to get item by _id from mongoose to delete it using

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express, mongoose, redux

I have react/redux **component**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import _ from 'lodash';
import {
  onDeleteItem,
  onChangeItemState
} from '../actions/actions.js'

import {
  Button
} from 'reactstrap';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  trStore: state
});

class Contenttr extends Component {
  deleteItem() {
    this.props.onDeleteItem(this.props.id);
  }
  changeItem() {
    this.props.onChangeItemState(this.props.id);
  }
  render() {
    return  (
      <tr>
        <td className="text-center"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x50" alt="Logo" /></td>
        <td className="text-center">{this.props.keywords}</td>
        <td className="text-center">{this.props.place}</td>
        <td className="text-center"><Button color="danger" size="sm" onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this)}>Delete</Button></td>
        <td className="text-center"><Button color="primary" size="sm" onClick={this.changeItem.bind(this)}>Change</Button></td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { onDeleteItem, onChangeItemState })(Contenttr);
```

I made **API**, to delete item from mongodb (mongoose):

```
router.route('/items/:item_id')
    // delete the item with this id (accessed at DELETE http://localhost:3001/api/item/:item_id)
    .delete(function(req, res) {
        Item.remove({
            _id: req.params.item_id
        }, function(err, item) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
        });
    });
```

In my **reducer** I use it this way to delete it from state:

```
else if (action.type === "DELETE_ITEM") {
    const delId = action.id;
    const filtered = _.filter(state.filtered,(o) => 
      o.id !== delId
    );
    const itemsList = _.filter(state.filtered,(o) => 
      o.id !== delId
    );
    // console.log('DELETE_ITEM', filtered, "delId", delId);
    return {
      ...state,
      filtered,
      itemsList
    }
```

My **action** file looks this way:

```
export function onDeleteItem(id) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/api/items/:${id}`)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({type:"DELETE_ITEM", id: id});
      })
  }
}
```

I'm facing issue, that to delete item using action I need to pass _id from component to action using onDeleteItem function. But basic `this.props._id` shows me `undefined`. How to get this _id or rewrite correctly API?

Comment: you have to bing *id* into your component as props, if it present in url params then add in mapStateToProps from url params

Comment: I dont understand how to bind itas props to component. I can't understand why this.props.id, this.props.keywords works, but this.props._id is.not.

Comment: Do you have a parent component? it looks like that you should pass it from there

Comment: @TheReason, you are right. I completely forgot that it comes not from state or databse, but from parent component. Thank you!